# Term for disappointment beyond all expectations?

Tags: terminology, disambiguities

"Utterly disappointed" comes to mind, but I am also looking for something to include worse than feared, despite hoping for the best.

For example, a situation where the expectations are reasonable, but the situation fails to even be understood properly from the beginning yielding to a wholly incorrect result.

Comment: Rats! or perhaps Dammit!

Comment: It depends on your local culture. Some might say that something was *a humbling experience* while others might say they were *devastated*, or possibly that *there is nowhere to go but up*.

Comment: You are crushed.

Answer (score 3):

[**Crestfallen**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crestfallen) sort of works.  Literally:

> ```
> :  having a drooping crest or hanging head
> :  feeling shame or humiliation :  dejected
> ```

Commonly used to imply a visage of extreme disappointment.

Answer (score 2):

I believe ***confound*** comes very close to what you want: *surprise beyond expectations* (which can result in disappointment if the result is negative).

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confound):

> **confound**
> *VERB*
> *[WITH OBJECT]*
>
> **1 *Cause surprise or confusion in (someone), especially by not according with their expectations:***
>
> the inflation figure *confounded* economic analysts
>
> So again like a good politician I shall try to tailor my ideology to
> make it sound more attuned to a reality that surprises and *confounds*
> me.
>
> The movie never attempts to surprise or *confound* us.
>
> If you're a fan of either of these artists then this release isn't
> going to surprise or *confound* you.
>
> ***1.1 Prove (a theory or expectation) wrong*:**
>
> the rise in prices *confounded* expectations
>
> At the same time, the electorate behaves now and then in totally
> unexpected ways - throwing up verdicts that *confound* popular
> expectation.
>
> If we think of the average 18th-century male as being a condescending
> misogynist, then this man *confounds* our expectations.
>
> Instead what you get is something inventive and of the moment - they
> play tunes from their CD's, but they also like mixing stuff up and
> *confounding* expectations.

There are several synonyms, some even connoting a stronger sense of surprise/disappointment but not necessarily the *beyond expectations* part.

Answer (score 0):

**"disillusioned"**, seems to fit.

> - [**disillusioned**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disillusioned) (adjective) - disappointed that something is not as good, valuable, true, etc., as it had seemed

e.g.

" I've become very disillusioned with politics."

"Most of those who once loved the prime minister have now become disillusioned with his ideals."

"she became disillusioned with the idea of becoming a lawyer"